# Setting rootviewcontoller in AppDelagate after deleting SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, appdelegate

I deleted SceneDelegate.swift and deleted related entry from .plist file.

Since my project doesn't support iPad, I won't need any SceneDelegate thing. Am I right?

I use SwiftUI so there is also no Storyboard

Now in AppDelegate file

```
var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

  if (TegKeychain.get("ISLOGGEDIN") == "1") {

           //present WelcomeScreen.swift

        } else {

            //present Login.Swift
        }

        return true
    }
```

Other files

```
struct Login: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Login")
    }
}

struct WelcomeScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("WelcomeScreen")
    }
}
```

I searched the web and was not able to find any helpful info about how to present a view controller without a storyboard.

Comment: what inside `//present WelcomeScreen.swift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is check-list of what I have done to rollback scenes support from new SwiftUI iOS project created from template:

1. Remove UIApplicationSceneManifest key from Info.plist
2. Remove all scene session related delegate methods from AppDelegate
3. Remove SceneDelegate
4. Updated AppDelegate as follows

```swift
    import UIKit
    import SwiftUI

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            let contentView = ContentView() // << default Hello World

            // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
            let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()

            return true
        }

    }
```

5. Build & Run - works.